# Not getting reponse after POST request through axios in react.js

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I am creating register and login page in react.js, but after sending post request from axios, I am not able to get back the response, and the .then function does not executes. Also the POST requests works correctly only some of the times(data is added to database).
And an error occurs in the backend, during the POST request -

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 25074)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\python\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)

  File "c:\python\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)

  File "c:\python\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()

  File "C:\Users\MUKUND\.virtualenvs\react-IVhYBaaI\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()

  File "C:\Users\MUKUND\.virtualenvs\react-IVhYBaaI\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)

  File "c:\python\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
    import axios from "axios";

class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeItem: {
                username:"",
                email: "",
                password: ""
            }
        };
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        alert(this.state.activeItem.email)
        //console.log("cred = ")
        //console.log(cred)
        var data = {
            username: this.state.activeItem.username,
            email: this.state.activeItem.email,
            password: this.state.activeItem.password
        }
        axios
            .post("http://localhost:8000/api/register/", data)
            .then(res => {
                alert("registered")
                console.log("response = ",res)
            })
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        let { name, value } = e.target;
        const activeItem = { ...this.state.activeItem, [name]: value };
        this.setState({ activeItem });
        //console.log(this.state.activeItem)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form align='center' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <h3>Sign Up</h3>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter username"
                            name="username"
                            value={this.state.activeItem.username}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email"
                            name="email"
                            value={this.state.activeItem.email}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password"
                            name="password"
                            value={this.state.activeItem.password}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block"/>
                </form>
                <div className="text-capitalize" id="opstatus">
                    Pending
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Register;
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("validated_data = ", validated_data)
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=validated_data['username'], email=validated_data['email'], password=validated_data['password'])
        
        return user
```

views.py

```
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        print("request = ",request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        print("user = ",user.password)
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
            })
```

Comment: I think the problem is in frontend(react.js) because Register and Login APIs are working fine when I checked from Postman.